# Why am I getting URI Unsupported

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-app-indexing

I'm using "Fetch as Google" to test deep linking into my Android app.  I uploaded an APK and tried a url.  You can see the url in the image.  I'm 100% sure that the first redacted section of the url matches the android:host in the manifest.  Is this something I'm doing wrong, or is this tool just really flaky?

```
            <data
                android:host="com.myapp.pro"
                android:pathPrefix="/obj/"
                android:scheme="android-app"
                />
```

[image]

Comment: Use `android:pathPrefix="/obj/*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Indexing requires HTTP based URLs. Take a look at the examples with HTTP and HTTPS handlers in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/public-content#route-incoming-links).